# How to direct user to actual 404 page when a check is false in single.php?

Tags: 404-error, single

Can someone tell me how to direct a user to the main 404 file instead of having to print an error message saying "file not found" in single.php?

For example:

```
<?php

if (!$myVar) {
  // go to 404.php and return an official file not found header
} else {
  // show the following HTML
}

?>
```

Comment: You want to just direct all logged in users not named "Mike" to a 404 page?

Comment: That was just a basic example, but what I'd like to do is send the user to the 404.php page if a certain condition is not met.

Comment: I know, what about users not logged in?

Comment: It's for users who are not logged in.

Comment: The please reword your question to say so, it is too confusing in its current form.

Comment: You're opening a php section the wrong way. It should be `<?php`, not `<php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) function to include the 404 template. Remember to do this instead of using `get_header()` or generating any output; otherwise you will have a duplicate.

```
<?php

if ( ! $myVar ) {
    status_header(404);

    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_404 = true;

    locate_template('404');
    return;
}

// otherwise, show the following HTML
```

Comment: Or just use `locate_template(); return;`.

Comment: I tried your code, but nothing's appearing where that function and return is. Am I missing something? I just have a file named 404.php in my theme directory. I would like it to redirect to this page so it includes File Not Found in the title element, body, etc.

Comment: Did you log out..?

Comment: I've updated my original code example above. It just checks if a variable is false and if so, should send the user to the 404. Sorry for the confusion about being logged in or not.

Comment: I've updated my answer as well. The `status_header()` function will let the browser (or Google) know that we're viewing a 404 page

Comment: I'm changing the title to "File Not Found" using a check for is_404() in my theme's header.php, but it's still showing the title of the post. Any ideas?

Comment: Try my updated code

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference. I'm running my check inside of the content area (after get_header() is called), so perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: The function needs to be at the very top of the page. Perhaps you can post your conditional code?

Comment: I see what you mean. The problem with that is the variable that is checked is determined in header.php. ;-) I'll just keep it as is as it would be too much to do to change things around. Thanks for your help!